# composite unique constraint error while updating the changeset

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, unique-constraint

I have a schema two_fa_details where answer and question_id are the fields and both are unique together..
Now when I am trying to insert data into it first it gets inserted but updating it next time isn't working..
It says constraint error.

I have a function set_two_factor_details written for updating table..
The function works fine for inserting the data very firsat time..but when iam updating it...its not working..i have a PUT API for this function.
this is my migration file for schema two_fa_details

```
def change do
    create table(:two_fa_details) do
      add :answer, :string
      add :userprofile_id, references(:user_profile, on_delete: :nothing)
      add :question_id, references(:questions, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:two_fa_details, [:userprofile_id])
    create index(:two_fa_details, [:question_id])

    create unique_index(:two_fa_details, [:userprofile_id, :question_id], name: :user_twofa_detail)
  end
```

here is a snippet of code

```
def set_twofactor_details(client_id, twofa_records) do
    user = Repo.get_by(UserProfile, client_id: client_id)
    twofa_records = Enum.map(twofa_records, &get_twofa_record_map/1)

    Enum.map(twofa_records, fn twofa_record ->
      Ecto.build_assoc(user, :two_fa_details)
      |> TwoFaDetails.changeset(twofa_record)
    end)
    |> Enum.zip(0..Enum.count(twofa_records))
    |> Enum.reduce(Ecto.Multi.new(), fn {record, id}, acc ->
      Ecto.Multi.insert_or_update(acc, String.to_atom("twfa_record_#{id}"), record)
    end)|>IO.inspect()
    |> Ecto.Multi.update(
      :update_user,
      Ecto.Changeset.change(user, two_factor_authentication: true, force_reset_twofa: false)
    )
    |> Repo.transaction()|>IO.inspect()
    |> case do
      {:ok, _} ->
        {:ok, :updated}

      {:error, _, changeset, _} ->
        error_string = get_first_changeset_error(changeset)
        Logger.error("Error while updating TWOFA: #{error_string}")
        {:error, 41001, error_string}
    end
  end
```

the output should be basically updating the table and returning two fa details updated message.
but in the logs its showing constraint error.please help me with this..Iam new to elixir.

```
{:error, :twfa_record_0,
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{answer: "a", question_id: 1, userprofile_id: 1},
   errors: [
     unique_user_twofa_record: {"has already been taken",
      [constraint: :unique, constraint_name: "user_twofa_detail"]}
   ],
   data: #Accreditor.TwoFaDetailsApi.TwoFaDetails<>,
   valid?: false
 >, %{}}
[error] Error while updating TWOFA: `unique_user_twofa_record` has already been taken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing it by using `upserts` for `ecto`
and it worked.
here is a snippet of code to refer

```
Ecto.Multi.insert_or_update(acc, String.to_atom("twfa_record_#{id}"), record,
       on_conflict: :replace_all_except_primary_key,
       conflict_target: [:userprofile_id, :question_id] )
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> the output should be basically updating the table and returning two fa details updated message.

But the code returns:

```
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{answer: "a", question_id: 1, userprofile_id: 1},
   errors: [
     unique_user_twofa_record: {"has already been taken",
      [constraint: :unique, constraint_name: "user_twofa_detail"]}
   ],
   data: #Accreditor.TwoFaDetailsApi.TwoFaDetails<>,
   valid?: false
 >
```

Look how it says `action: :insert`. So you are not updating, but inserting, which explain the error.

`insert_or_update` will only update a record if the record was loaded from the database. In your code, you are building records from scratch, and therefore they will always be an insert. You need to use `Repo.get` or similar to fetch them before passing them to the changeset so you can finally call `insert_or_update`.

Comment: can I do anything like using ```:on_conflict``` option in the ```insert_or_update``` function??

Comment: thank you for the help...however it got resolved by using ```upserts``` for```ecto```

Comment: Yes! upsert is another possible option for the problem, good point!